# Nested Forms with find_or_create_by method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been stuck on this issue all day now and I'm fairly certain there is an easy fix that I am just not seeing due to my inexperience. A bit of background on what I'm trying to do before I discuss my problem. I have a model called **Companies** that can have many **Locations**. Similarly, a **location** can have multiple **Companies**. Because of this I created a has_many :through relationship.

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_locations
  has_many :locations, :through => :company_locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_locations
  has_many :companies, :through => :company_locations
end

class CompanyLocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :location
end
```

Because of this structure, when a **Company's** location is created/updated I want to check whether this **location** (by name) exists. If it does, I use form the association between the **Company** and that **Location**. If it does not, the **location** is created and then the association is created. It is my understanding that the best way to do this is through a `find_or_create_by` method. However, the various ways I have tried do not seem to be creating this functionality.

Right now just to get something working my view for new **Companies** is this:

```
<h1> Add Company </h1>
<%= form_for :company, url: companies_path do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name%>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :website %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :website%>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
</p>

    <%=fields_for :locations do |location_form|%>
        <%= location_form.label :name, 'Location' %>
        <%= location_form.text_field :name %>
    <%end%>
<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Now inside the create action in my **Companies** controller is where I am experiencing difficulties. As said before, I want to check if the location that is being added to the company already exists or not. Because of this, I am using a `find_or_create_by` method. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to properly handle the strong params/slice the params in a way to make this work without error.

```
  def new
        @company = Company.new
        @company_locations = @company.company_locations.build
        @location = @company_locations.build_location
    end

  def create
        @company = Company.new(company_params)
        @location = Location.find_or_create_by(name: (company_params.slice(:location_attributes[0][:name)))
        @company.locations << @location
        @company.save 
        redirect_to @company
    end

   private 

    def company_params
        params.require(:company).permit(:name,:website, :description, location_attributes: [:name])
    end
```

Currently, I'm getting an error saying 'no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer' which leads me to believe that I am accessing the hash wrong, however, any other method I have tried results in the a **Location** being created with "NULL" set as the name. I'm really stumped on this one, and to completely honest I'm not sure I am approaching this nested form correctly. In the future, I hope to use JQuery/Javascript/Cocoon to be able to dynamically add fields in the form to add more locations at once. I've been trying to follow other Stack Overflow posts and forums to no avail. Any help/guidance is much appreciated! Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Still stuck on this one. Here is the params hash from the server log for an example company:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"xpDOq6D5YRZ3VUXLBLgu8SfRIkRXgMQHXIRUtArNp1smtXShB/i54fQQVEHgqy64kdj1R+u0t/JVihLCXQVZpg==",
 "company"=>{"name"=>"Google", "website"=>"www.google.com", "description"=>"Google is a search engine."},
 "locations"=>{"name"=>"Mountain View"},
 "commit"=>"Save Company"}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Params hash after Pavan's suggestions.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"xJHZVYSfHmjR3BOMS49yRzwD35NV5F7uyCou8yOmtKAktGNfI57Gn1KZAgavnHIOigoIkOnQLRvBJGiFdG5KXQ==",
 "company"=>{"name"=>"Logitech", "website"=>"www.logitech.com", "description"=>"This is logitech"},
 "locations"=>{"name"=>"Chicago"},
 "commit"=>"Save Company"}
```

**UPDATE 3**

Changed the form for tag to:

```
<%= form_for @company, url: companies_path do |f| %>
```

This is the new updated params hash:

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"UiiwNXzOiDqZd0Vv1dDu4jkyRQU4e9LKLixqKH+rvKCyDQo/289QzRoyVOUxw+6rjzuSBoRPoT8nIixeKGNCXQ==", 
"company"=>{"name"=>"Seagate", "website"=>"www.seagate.com", "description"=>"This is seagate"}, 
"locations"=>{"name"=>"Los Angeles "}, 
"commit"=>"Create Company"}
```

Comment: What are the `params` generated in the server log? Show us.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated the question with the params hash from the server log.

Comment: Can you show the `new` method?

Comment: Added. I'm not sure if I should be doing the 'find_or_create_by' here in the controller, or somewhere in the model as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of mistakes

#### You need to build the associations correctly

```
def new
  @company = Company.new
  @company_locations = @company.company_locations.build
  @location = @company.locations.build #since you have defined nested attributes in company    
end
```

#### Change `location_attributes` to `locations_attributes`

```
def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(:name,:website, :description, locations_attributes: [:name])
end
```

And try using `company_params.slice(:locations_attributes[0][:name])`

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately I am still getting this error: "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" when creating the @location instance. I am not sure why because it does seem like I am accessing the hash correctly? Thoughts?

Comment: @R.N Can you post the params that are generated now with my changes?

Comment: @R.N Ok. Just do `params[:locations][:name]`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Can you explain why strong params do not work here?

Comment: @R.N I have no clue, but try changing `<%= form_for :company, url: companies_path do |f| %>` to `<%= form_for @company, url: companies_path do |f| %>` and see the `params`. And tell me are the same or not?

Comment: The "commit" action changed from "Save Company" to "Create Company". (i.e. it shows "commit"=>"Create Company" now).

Comment: @R.N Are the rest of the `params` same? Do you see any `locations_attributes` in the hash?

Comment: Yes everything else is the same. Locations is still in the hash. I have updated the question with the new params hash. Thanks again for all your help - really appreciate it.

Comment: @R.N Try changing `<%=fields_for :locations do |location_form|%>` to `<%=fields_for @location do |location_form|%>` and see if there is `locations_attributes`

Comment: It is still `locations` and not `locations_attributes`.